# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number,проблема с sql запросом

Tags: php, sql, веб-программирование, pdo, httpbackend

```
public static function getSearchProductsListByCategory($value1,$value2,$categoryId, $page = 1)
{
    $limit = Product::SHOW_BY_DEFAULT;
    $offset = ($page - 1) * self::SHOW_BY_DEFAULT;
    $db = Db::getConnection();

    $sql = 'SELECT id, name, price, is_new FROM product '
            . 'WHERE price BETWEEN :value1 AND :value2 AND status = "1" AND category_id = :category_id'
            . 'ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset';

    $result = $db->prepare($sql);

    $result->execute(array(":value1"=>$value1,":value2"=>$value2,":category_id"=>$categoryId,":limit"=>$limit,":offset"=>$offset));

    $i = 0;
    $products = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
        $products[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
        $products[$i]['name'] = $row['name'];
        $products[$i]['price'] = $row['price'];
        $products[$i]['is_new'] = $row['is_new'];
        $i++;
    }
    return $products;
}
```

Comment: А разве могут limit/offset быть параметрами?

Comment: +1 к коментарию Akina,  а также добавлю что в `mysql` нет ключевого слова `OFFSET`. Лимит указывается как  `LIMIT 1,10`, т.е. через запятую

Comment: LIMIT и OFFSET вроде бы можно указывать, используя `$result->bindValue(':limit', (int) $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT); `

Comment: Во второй строке у запроса пробел в конце поставьте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Непосредственно ошибка: выведите на экран переменную `$sql` и увидите параметр под названием `category_idORDER`. Внимание на пробелы. Вообще редко доводится видеть построчно разбитый SQL через конкатенацию. Чаще его оформляют одним блоком текста в кавычках вот так:

```
 $sql = 'SELECT id, name, price, is_new FROM product 
        WHERE price BETWEEN :value1 AND :value2 AND status = "1" AND category_id = :category_id
        ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset';
```

---

С указанием limit и offset через параметры есть некоторая проблема в комбинация фактов:

- SQL-парсер mysql считает, и довольно обоснованно, что limit и offset должны быть строго числами
- PHP PDO по-умолчанию использует эмуляцию подготовленных выражений
- execute с передачей массива всех параметров - дико удобно, но ориентирован только на строковые параметры

В итоге PHP подставляет строки в запрос вместо чисел, получается `limit '10'` (даже если тип переменной был числовой, да), на что очень обижается парсер. Парсер mysql изменять как-то несподручно, поэтому остаётся два варианта:

- выключить эмуляцию подготовленных выражений:

  ```
  $pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
  ```

  Для mysql однозначных минусов такого решения назвать не могу.
- привязывать параметры с явным указанием числового типа:

  ```
  $stmt->bindValue(':lim', (int) $limit, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
  ```

---

И у вас какой-то очень странный и слишком многословный `return $result->fetchAll();` написан в конце метода.

Comment: Спасибо , огромное.
Как-то даже неловко за такую банальную ошибку